# react-native-vector-icons or @expo/vector-icons not rendering on android device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

In my expo project which has not been ejected,Icons are not being rendered on android.I installed the package using npm.I cons are being rendered on web browser but not on android .

`npm i react-native-vector-icons`

`import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';`

`<MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-box" color={color} size={26} />`

Comment: Can you try removing curly brackets from MaterialCommunityIcons and test import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

Comment: i am also facing same issue i tryied with {} and without {} and as import Icon from '' (globle folder)

Answer (score 1):

While using react-native-vector-icons no curly brackets

```
 import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
```

While using @expo/vector-icons

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Comment: I have tried with and without curly braces.but no luck

Comment: This works fine for both in case you can check with the color provided

Comment: Color does not change anything

Comment: I meant doing so works fine in Android you can check on other attributes as such color or the view it is added in might be overlapping the icon